# LXDE .desktop file permission issue

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I’m trying to run a Python script via a desktop icon/shortcut/launcher on a Raspberry Pi using Raspbian and LXDE. I have to use a desktop launcher since the script has to be started via a tiny touchscreen only accepting left-clicks and without a keyboard.
I *think* that I have a permission issue since the script fails at a point where it should execute some system commands which require root.

The script works if I do the following:

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter `sudo python3 program.py`

I tried to replicate this behavior with a `.desktop` file using the following config:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=sudo python3 program.py
Terminal=true
Icon=path/to/icon.png
Name=Program Launcher
```

I suppose I missed something obvious, but since I don’t work with Linux usually I’m a bit lost here.

**Edit:** The problem was not a missing permission but an incorrectly assumed working directory and is now solved. Sorry for my confusion.
In detail: during development the script was started from its own folder while the desktop launcher used `/home/pi` as working directory. In general that's not a problem, but in the script a hardcoded path was used and a required file not found when using the launcher. The real problem was sloppy swallowed and the status code of a permission issue returned. So it was simply a bad code issue.

Answer (score 1):

As [docs for desktop entries](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) says:

> The Exec key must contain a command line. A command line consists of
>   an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments.
>   The executable program can either be specified with its full path or
>   with the name of the executable only. **If no full path is provided the
>   executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the
>   desktop environment**. The name or path of the executable program may
>   not contain the equal sign ("="). Arguments are separated by a space.

It leads to conclusion, that maybe python3 is not within $PATH used by the desktop environment. Try to check full path of your `python3` and `sudo` with:

```
whereis python3
whereis sudo
```

on my Archlinux it gives me `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/sudo`. Try to modify your Dekstop entry to something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/python3 program.py
Terminal=true
Icon=path/to/icon.png
Name=Program Launcher
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks I tried that. However, the real problem was an incorrectly assumed path. My bad I didn't realize that earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrectly assumed path? Can you please, clarify it for someone who will have similar problem?

Comment: Sure, I updated the OP. It was really just badly written code and me mislead by the returned error.